Attempted import error: 'SWRConfig' is not exported from 'swr' (imported as 'SWRConfig')
./node_modules/@clerk/shared/dist/react/index.mjs
Attempted import error: 'SWRConfig' is not exported from 'swr' (imported as 'SWRConfig').

I wanted to using clerk for authorization and when I install the package this issue arise

I was having the same issue and found there was an import error I was facing.
I was importing the component something like this in my next.js app
import { SignedIn, SignedOut, SignInButton } from "@clerk/clerk-react";


Which cannot be imported into the server-side page

Instead of import everything from "@clerk/nextjs"
import { ClerkProvider, SignedIn, SignedOut, SignInButton } from "@clerk/nextjs";

This will fix the issue

I had the same problem and this fixed the issue for me

Seems like you forgot to put the 'use client' directive on top of your file.

try by uninstalling npm and install yarn by whole follow
cmds:
yarn add @clerk/clerk-sdk
yarn clerk init

worked for me.
